# Any clue why logout might not unsubscribe API call?

Tags: angular, identityserver4

I have the followin code in Component *base class*:

```
//@Directive()
//export abstract class BaseComponent {

 unsubscriber$ = new ReplaySubject(1);

 ngOnInit(): void {
     this.oAuthService.events
         .pipe
         (
             filter(event => event?.type === 'logout'),
             takeUntil(this.unsubscriber$),
             tap(() => {
                 this.unsubscriber$.next(null);
                 this.unsubscriber$.complete();
             })
         )
         .subscribe();
 }

//}
```

The idea of this - to unsubscribe from any API service call which is being loaded when I'm pressing "Logout" button:

```
//export class SomeComponent extends BaseComponent {

 this.someService
   .someApiMethod()
   .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscriber$))
   .subscribe(() => {
    ...
  });

//}
```

However, such unsubscription seems not to be working - after the code inside "tap" is invoked - `someApiMethod` is still called (producing error 401 of course). Am I missing something?

Just for information. I use `this.unsubscriber$` in the same way in `ngOnDestroy` and there it works as expected.

Comment: why is it in `tap` an not `subscribe`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to move subscription to a construction time to ensure it is the first one to be processed. Also it could be refactored a little bit

```
//@Directive()
//export abstract class BaseComponent {

 unsubscriber$ = new ReplaySubject(1);

 constructor(oAuthService:OAuthService) {
     oAuthService.events
         .pipe
         (
             filter(event => event?.type === 'logout'),
             take(1)
         )
         .subscribe(()=>{
                 this.unsubscriber$.next(null);
                 this.unsubscriber$.complete();});
         }

//}
```

also make sure that `oAuthService.events` is not `observedOn` nor `subscribeOn` on some async dispatchers

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I followed your recomendations - unfortunately, it did not help. But I've noticed a very strange thing: when I put breakpoint on this.unsubscriber$.next(null) - it fires sometimes once, sometimes 2-3 times! After I release the last one of those - API calls from this Component page with error 401 appear again. Another strange thing is that actually logout works only from Home (root) page - from other pages it eventually redirects me to Home page without logging off. PS. There's no any interaction with `oAuthService.events` besides this one in Component's base class.

Comment: At the same time I "caught" only ONE firing of `this.eventsSubject.next(new OAuthInfoEvent('logout'));`

Comment: As for variable number of subscription calls, most probably it happens exactly the same amount of times you create component. Keep in mind that this example DOES NOT include subscription cancelling on component destruction.

Comment: I even can't imagine the way to find a route cause here: the debug in my case is very boresome and confusing. Each component matches its own route and I can't see any way it can be created more than once when visiting the specific route...